# XHTML OrderedList and UnorderedList Invalid validation

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to use the ul and ol tags to create two seperate lists on a page, but everytime I try to validate the page I get "document type does not allow element "ul" here. I have tried moving the tags around and ive checked every tag that I have opened to ensure they are all closed. I also tried moving just that section of code to a new page and it throws the same error in the validation. I'm out of ideas, any help you can offer is greatly appreciated. It displays correctly, but I need it to pass validation.

```
<ol>
<li>USA</li>
<li>Canada</li>
<li>Sweden</li>
</ol>
</h2>
<hr/>
<h3>List Example (Order NOT important)</h3>
<h2> Things to Pick Up</h2>
<h3>
<ul>
<li>Milk</li>
<li>Eggs</li>
<li>Bread</li>
<li>Cheese</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a list inside a heading. You are trying to put one inside a sub-sub-heading (`<h3>`). (You probably have one inside a sub-heading (`<h2>`) too, but the start tag is missing from that.

Put the lists after the headings.

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) under "Contexts in which this element can be used" for other places that you are allowed to place lists.

Comment: I fixed the h2/h3 errors, but I want to keep the same font that it gave me, so should I put the h3 tags insde of each individual list item? Fixed it , thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: No. You should use stylesheets. You should only use a heading if the data you are describing is a heading.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests with your code and tryed to validate with W3C validator.
Here are my observations about your piece of code with the proper corrections applied.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ryan's solution</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <ol>
      <li>USA</li>
      <li>Canada</li>
      <li>Sweden</li>
     </ol>
     <h2> <!--This oppening tag was added by me--> Hello World!</h2> <!--Why are you closing what was not oppened?-->
     <hr/>
     <h3>List Example (Order NOT important)</h3>
     <h2> Things to Pick Up</h2>
     <h3> <!--Where is the closing for this tag?--> Hello World!</h3><!--The closing tag was added by me-->
     <ul>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Eggs</li>
      <li>Bread</li>
      <li>Cheese</li>
     </ul>
     </body>
</html>
```

This corretions have been aproved by W3c validator.The explanation for the errors I found are in the comments.

I'm sorry if this answer is not fully clear and elegant. This is my first answer here, and i'm learning how to help people :)

Good luck with your coding !